# Where does this proof of $R^n\cong R^m\Rightarrow m=n$ break down for noncommutative rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It can be that $R\cong R^2$ for some ring as wikipedia says, something like the column finite ring. In [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/modulesoverPID.pdf) the author proved in lemma 1.1 something different. But I could not find any mistakes in the proof. What is happening?

Comment: I don't know what the example in Wikipedia is, but I'd say the problem might be the fact the not every ring has a maximal ideal. (If it has a multiplication identity it is true though)

Comment: Note that the same (common) proof is also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number#Examples), but you need to click on "[show]" to see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that maximal ideals in noncommutative rings do not always produce a field when you use them to make the quotient ring.

The proof given there relies entirely on the fact that $R/M$ is at least a division ring, so that ordinary linear algebra takes over.

In general, $R/M$ is merely a simple ring, and there is no corresponding dimensionality that you can use to make the same argument.

Comment: I see, so the literature means commutative rings?

Comment: @CO2 it says “commutative “ right in the theorem you referenced.